# C# error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I try to make an app which manages client's contacts. The form is very very simple. There are: panel (inside this panel are labels with names, emails, etc.) and a listbox which shows all saved contacts in sdf file. I have one big problem. I want to refresh the listbox content via a method in another class. I set the listbox as public, debugger shows no errors during the project build. When the form loads, this message is prompted (via try-catch exception): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". I tried to do this project differently - everything was written in one class. Here's the code:

**database.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace Contacts
{
    class Database
    {
        public static void RefreshListBox()
        {
            SqlCeConnection connection = null;
                try
                {
                var form1 = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;
                connection = new SqlCeConnection("Datasource = C:\\Kontakty.sdf");
                connection.Open();
                SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Contacts", connection);
                SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    form1.listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1));
                }
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Contacts
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database.RefreshListBox();
        }


    }
}
```

Does anyone here know what is wrong?

PS: kontakty = contacts (in Czech ;-))

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and stepping through until you see the error?

Comment: Which line in your try block is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
public static void RefreshListBox(ListBox listBox)
  ...
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    listBox.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1));
  }
```

And then:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Database.RefreshListBox(this.listBox1);
}
```

Other than that, you really shouldn't be passing forms or listboxes into database classes.  It should be the other way around-- your form should just get the data from the class and populate the listbox there.

Answer (score 0):

Form.ActiveForm is probably null because From1 is still being loaded and probably not yet visible and hence not active.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to pass a reference to your listbox to the RefreshListBox() function.

There is no reason for your class to have any knowledge or reference to Form1.

try this in your form:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {             
      Database.RefreshListBox(this.listBox1); 
 }
```

And this in your class:

```
public static void RefreshListBox(ListBox listbox)             
{                 
      SqlCeConnection connection = null;
      try
      {
           listbox.Items.Clear()    //I assume you may want to refresh?

           connection = new SqlCeConnection("Datasource = "C:\\Kontakty.sdf");
           connection.Open();                     
           SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Contacts", connection);
           SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
           while (reader.Read())   
           {
               listbox.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1));
           }
      }
      catch(Exception exc)
      {                         
          MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);                  
      }
}
```

I've left out a lot (like persisting the selected item(s)), but you get the idea.

Also - don't use field index for your SQL return values if you don't specify their order.  Call the fields by name (I know you can't with the CE SqlDataReader) or better yet: specify them (and their order) in your SQL statement.  You never know when a DB will get moved or regenerated and the default order from "Select * From ..." will be munged, plus if fields get added in later versions, you're only wasting bandwidth/data space to return their values if you're not going to use them.